# Detecting Collision Between Clones Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, clone, collision

Is it possible to identify a collision between a "clone"? I must launch a projectile as a clone and destroy it when it touches an object. Is there any way to use tags and the `void OnCollisionEnter()` function? Here is my code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
{
    shootProjectile();
}

void shootProjectile()
{
    var ForwardDirection = cameraTarget.transform.forward;
    var RightDirection = cameraTarget.transform.right;
    var UpDirection = cameraTarget.transform.up;

    GameObject clone = Instantiate(Projectile, transform.position + 1 * ForwardDirection, transform.rotation);

    clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(ForwardDirection * 600);
    clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(UpDirection * 200);
    clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(RightDirection * 200);

    Destroy(clone, 3.0f); // Destroy the clone after 5 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a tag to a prefab. But if you just want to destroy the projectile when it hits anything. then you don't need a tag.

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject)

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work as I am using other gameObjects in the script too and the script is too large to post in this comment reply

Comment: @R-ty_dragon1_YT put this in a new script and attach it to the projectile prefab and make sure the projectile prefab has a collider

Comment: I've done what you suggested but my clone doesn't seem to detect the collision. I used debugs but it wasn't even running the collision check yet the projectile still bounced around on the floor and nothing got logged in the console

Comment: both the surface and projectile should have colliders and rigidbody should not be set to kinematic